Кнопка меню в телеграм боте
Как для разных групп пользователей телеграм ботом назначить разные команды(в меню)?
Про setMyCommands и deleteMyCommands знаю, интересует сама логика, в какой момент установить, когда проверять.

Укажите в метках на каком языке и библиотеке реализуете бота, чтобы получить более точный ответ на вопрос

Логика проста: 1. у вашего бота должна быть база данных с пользователями и их правами; 2. отдавать соответствующее меню согласно их прав.  Если у вас нет такой базы, то — никак.  Не зная числа потенциальных и текущих пользователей и платформы сложно что-то советовать, но простейшее решение может быть даже текстовым файлом в виде json либо БД SQLite. При наличии базы последовательность проста — первым делом авторегистрация любого пользователя в базе с минимальными правами.
